# I have passed a button in TabLayoutPanel and while clicking on button nothing is happening in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have added a button in TabLayoutPanel, and on button click I want to display something, but noting is happening.

Here is sample code for which I was trying :

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    final TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(2.5, Unit.EM);
    final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
    final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();

    //Tab
    sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");
    nameField.getElement().setId("PID");
    sendButton.getElement().setId("sendButton");

    String row = searchAnyTransaction(sendButton, nameField);

    tabPanel.add(new HTML(row), "Transaaction Status");
    tabPanel.add(new HTML("that"), "[that]");
    tabPanel.add(new HTML("the other"), "[the other]");
    tabPanel.setPixelSize(500, 400);
    final RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();

    rp.add(tabPanel);

    nameField.setFocus(true);
    nameField.selectAll();

    //On sendButton click , Clickhandler event should call.
    // Create a handler for the sendButton and nameField
            sendButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    rp.add(sendButton);
                    //how to add dialog box to display 
                    //  Want to display something.          
                }

            });

}



public static String searchAnyTransaction(Button sendbutton, TextBox namefield2){


    String htmlForm = ""
            + "<TABLE BORDER=\"2\" ><TR><TH height=\"40\" style=\"width:20%;\"><h3 class=“Search” role=\"tab\" aria-expanded=\"true\" aria-selected=\"true\" tabindex=\"0\">Search</h3></TH>"
            + "<TH height=\"40\" style=\"width:20%;\"><label for=\"fname\">PID:</label></TH><TD height=\"40\" style=\"width:50%;\">" + namefield2 
            + "<TD height=\"40\" style=\"width:20%;\">"+ sendbutton +"</TD></TR>"
            + "</TABLE>";

    return htmlForm;
}
```

So I want to display something on button click. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Do not build your form as a string.

When you try to concatenate a widget (`Button` or `TextBox`) with a string, the widget's `toString()` method is called.

```
"string" + sendbutton + "string"
```

is indeed:

```
"string" + sendbutton.toString() + "string"
```

`toString()` returns html snippet of the widget, but it will not contain any handlers. That's why the `ClickHandler` will never be executed.

Instead, you should build your form using some panel, like [`Grid`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Grid.html) or [`FlexTable`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html).

For example:

```
public static Grid searchAnyTransaction(Button sendbutton, TextBox namefield2){
    Grid grid = new Grid(1, 4);
    grid.setText(0, 0, "Search");
    grid.setText(0, 1, "PID:");
    grid.setWidget(0, 2, namefield2);
    grid.setWidget(0, 3, sendbutton);

    return grid;
}
```

and add it to the TabPanel like this:

```
tabPanel.add(searchAnyTransaction(sendButton, nameField), "Transaaction Status");
```